# Performing a SELECT immediately followed by an UPDATE in Access via .NET

Tags: .net, ms-access

my question is relatively simple but I haven't found an answer yet. I have a table which only contains only one row. This row has two columns, ClientCode and a ClientIndex.

I have a select query which looks like:

```
SELECT i.ClientCode + FORMAT(i.ClientIndex, "000000") FROM Indexes as I;
```

Now after I've run the select I want to increment the ClientIndex by one.

```
UPDATE Indexes SET ClientIndex = ClientIndex + 1;
```

Motivation: I want to be able to create sequential Report Numbers. So every time I generate a report I want the ClientIndex to increment. For this to work I will need to lock the table, select my number, increment the Index and unlock the table.

Is this possible in MS Access 2013? It's trivial in Sql using a Stored Procedure; but the requirements state Access and there is no way around this requirement. Furthermore, I'm building a client application (using .NET and F#) which will retrieve the Report Number.

**EDIT**: It seems like people do not really get the question. I want both statements, the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` to run within the same execution. I do *NOT* want to call the select and update after each other from some client.

The SP in plain old t-sql it would look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE something
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result as nchar(10);
    set @result = <<select query>>;
    <<update query>>;
    select @result;
END
```

**EDIT:** I'm building a .NET F# application which will call the Access database and retrieve the Report Number. This application will run in a Windows Service on a Windows server. This Report Number could be called about 100 times concurrently at large intervals.

Comment: whats wrong with your update statement? (except it doesn't have a where condition)

Comment: Why don't you just _try_? It would have taken less time than writing the question ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want them to run "after each other" as in "in the same statement" I do not want the calling code to have to do two calls to the database in order to get this to work. In other words, I want a `SELECT` statement and an `UPDATE` statement to run within the same execution.

Comment: Edited my question, if it is still unclear, please let me know I can try and explain it better. But the idea is to generate a unique "business number" per report within one single statement. (So yes, concat string, get something like 2015-RPT-000001 for the first report and 2015-RPT-000002 for the second one. I've dumbed done the creation of the number because that is not important. Important is that a single execution returns a value and updates the database.

Comment: @HansUp If it is possible to call this VBA procedure from .NET code and if 2 concurrent calls to the VBA script execute serial so that there is no chance at double numbers that would be suitable. (Granted that I would have hoped to do it in a more "sql-y" way) - Thank you for thinking along, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want the calling code to have to do two calls to the database in order to get this to work. In other words, I want a SELECT statement and an UPDATE statement to run within the same execution.

The Access Database Engine does not support multi-statement batches, so you cannot execute ...

```sql
SELECT i.ClientCode + FORMAT(i.ClientIndex, "000000") FROM Indexes as I;
UPDATE Indexes SET ClientIndex = ClientIndex + 1;
```

... all in one go. Each SQL statement would have to be executed separately.

Now, that would not be a problem if the two statements were executed in a transaction where the isolation level was "serializable". Unfortunately, neither the Access ODBC Driver nor the Access OLEDB Provider supports `System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable` for transactions. The highest level of isolation they support is `ReadCommitted`, and that is not strict enough to prevent two processes from getting the same ClientIndex.

As far as I know the only way to mimic a serializable transaction is to use Access DAO with pessimistic locking, like this:

```cs
// COM Reference required:
// Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"\\DINSDALE\Public\test\locktestBE.accdb");
Recordset rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ClientIndex FROM Indexes",
        RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset,
        RecordsetOptionEnum.dbFailOnError,
        LockTypeEnum.dbPessimistic);
bool keepTrying = true;
while (keepTrying)
{
    try
    {
        rst.Edit();
        int nextId = rst.Fields["ClientIndex"].Value;  // get next ID,
        rst.Fields["ClientIndex"].Value = nextId + 1;  // increment value, and
        rst.Update();                                  // write it back
        rst.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("The assigned ID is {0}", nextId);
        keepTrying = false;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
    {
        if (!e.Message.StartsWith("Could not update; currently locked by user"))
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
db.Close();
```

However, you really should think carefully before proceeding with using the Access database as the data store for your service. Handling high concurrency and performing granular locking are not strong suits of the Access Database Engine. (Microsoft "strongly recommends against using Access in web applications" for several reasons  – ref: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database) – and it sounds like many of those reasons would apply to your application as well.)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I fully understand that Access is not good at concurrency and now I understand that batch statements are not supported. I wish I had other database options but I'm stuck with this one.

I think the above code is that only option, I guess I'll have to sacrifice parallelism for practicality.

Comment: Might there be another way of generating a unique, sequential "report number" from an Access database without needing a batch statement?
I would make another question, but it was a part of the original question, so if this "follow-up" is inappropriate in any way, let me know.